# Google Earth Engine ERA 5 Precipitation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, climate

I am generating the estimation of the ERA 5 climate dataset. I read all the information, but I have a question.
I need the precipitation data for a town area in Germany. I chose the total precipitation in m. Is it suitable/significant for smaller regions and I can use it for interpreting precipitation?

Also I made a code in GEE. The values I get are in meters, but because of the small amount I am asking myself if it is possible to transform the chart for better interpretation?

Also I like to add a Layer but think I'm missing something in the code.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Flaraemsinghoff%2FStart%3AKlima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are on the right track, just convert to the correct units (dataset is in meters) so divide it to get cm or mm depending on what you want.

```
var Precipitation = function(img){
  // the units of precipitation are depth in metres: divide to get cm / mm
  var bands = img.select('total_precipitation').divide(0.01).clip(table);
  return bands.rename('Precipitaion')
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};
```

Adding the first image:

```
// select the first image
Map.addLayer (eraPrec.first().clip(table),{},'Niederschlag')
```

Not sure what you where trying with the `ee.Reducer.mean()`, that most of the time is used to get mean per year or whatever timeframe you select.

I reproduced your example but with a different set of geometries as your assets where not shared:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a3133a81b694c4e677c5f00e7a348568